# Preview with meteor-autoform

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, meteor-autoform

I use `meteor-autoform` with

```
{{> quickForm collection="Pages" id="insertPageForm" type="insert"}}
```

but I also want a box below the form with a preview area just like here on SO.

I just don't know how to bind a keyup trigger to the autoform field.

With a plain helper I could have html:

```
<textarea class="text"></textarea>
<div class="preview"></div>
```

and js:

```
"change .text": function (e) {
    $(".preview").text($(e.target).text());
}
```

or something like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you to customize form using autoform then you have to use **afQuickField** ([doc](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-autoform#afquickfield)).

I tried with below code and I think this what you want.

common/schema.js

```
Pages = new Mongo.Collection("pages");

Pages.attachSchema(new SimpleSchema({
    text : {
        type: String,
        label: "Text",
        optional : true,
        max: 1000,
        autoform: {
            rows: 2
        }
    }
}));
```

.html

```
<template name="stest">
    {{#autoForm id="insertPageForm" collection="Pages" type='insert'}}
        {{> afQuickField name='text'}}
        <div class="preview"></div>
        <div>
            <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </div>
    {{/autoForm}}
</template>
```

.js

```
Template.stest.events({
    "keyup textarea[name=text]": function (e, t) {
        t.$(".preview").text($(e.target).val());
    }
});
```

Hope this help you.
Cheers!

Comment: Thank you. Do you also know how to put the preview inside `{{#markdown}}...{{/markdown}}`?

Comment: i don't have idea about this `{{#markdown}}...{{/markdown}}`. Can you tell me specifically what it does??? So, that i can try this...

Comment: It's a built-in template helper (http://docs.meteor.com/#/basic/markdown). I have tried `{{#markdown}}{{text}}{{/markdown}}` and a helper: `text: function (e, t) { return $("textarea[name=text]").val(); }`. It does change the text but it doesn't get formatted with markdown